# Use CONSTRAINT keyword when creating a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

A question on using the `CONSTRAINT` keyword when creating a new table. I saw some code like this below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
    keycol INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) 
        CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY,
    datacol NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
```

My question is, isn't `NOT NULL` also a `CONSTRAINT` the same as `PRIMARY KEY`, so why do we place `CONSTRAINT` keyword for `PRIMARY KEY`, but not for `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Conceptually thats probably true - but I guess you'd consider `NOT NULL` to be a low level, but fundamental constraint. Whereas primary keys and foreign keys are higher level, more complex.

Comment: Agree with @DaleBurrell, NOT NULL is at the column level... and PK is more of a table level constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NOT NULL constraint can be modified using an `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` statement. Therefore, an explicit name for a NOT NULL constraint is useless. The name of a NOT NULL constraint will not be stored in the database's metadata.

Other constraints (primary key, foreign key, unique, check, and default) can be removed using an `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT` statement. For such statements, a constraint name has to be specified. So technically a constraint name is always required for such constraints.

But **constraint names are always optional in the SQL syntax**, so you can always omit `CONSTRAINT [constraintname]` when creating a constraint. So this is valid SQL too:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
    keycol INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    datacol NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
```

However, for constraints that actually will require a constraint name for removal, the DBMS will automatically generate a constraint name if one is not supplied explicitly. In the above `CREATE TABLE` statement, the primary key will get a name like `PK__T1__98D78B44D915DA1F`.

**Explicitly naming your primary keys, foreign keys, unique constraints, check constraints and default constraints will ease future maintenance of your database tables.** If you explicitly name your constraints, you always know exactly how the constraints are named. If you want to remove a "nameless" constraint, you have to look up its generated name in the database's metadata first (which I consider to be quite ugly and complex).

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [`CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)

> CONSTRAINT Is an optional keyword that indicates the start of the
>   definition of a PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL, UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY, or CHECK
>   constraint.

so you can use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword there if you want

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
    keycol INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) 
        CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY,
    datacol NVARCHAR(40) CONSTRAINT Foo NOT NULL
);
```

This is pointless though as the constraint keyword is only ever required for constraints when specifying a name. And when used with `NOT NULL` this does not actually create a constraint object in `sys.constraints`, so the name is not stored anywhere. It is just a property of the column whether or not it is nullable.